# Use DAO pattern for access web session

Tags: java, design-patterns, session, servlets, dao

I want to use the [Dao pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html) for control the access to web Session.

My idea is control all the elements that there are in Session using one DAO, if someone want to obtain for example the email he has to write something like that:

```
    sessionDAO.getEmail();
```

or

```
    UserData userData = sessionDAO.getUserData();
    userData.getEmail();
```

For put the email in Sesion i want to do:

```
    public void setEmail(String email){
           ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
           HttpSession session = requestAttributes.getRequest().getSession();
           session.setAttribute(SessionDAO.EMAIL,email);
    }
```

With this way I can always check what values are in my Session. I don't want that anyone can do this:

```
   request.setAttribute("email", "example@gmail.com");
```

Because for exmple in other part of my code someone can repit the code because he don't know that the email is already in Session.

**Is well used the DAO pattern here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather call this approach a `context` instead of `DAO` (*execution context*, *runtime context*, *HTTP context* - you name it).

JNDI is implemented using similar approach. Spring has `ApplicationContext`. There are probably many more examples like this.

DAO is dedicated more for separating POJOs from their retrieval and can confuse whoever reads your code in the future, including yourself.

But anyway the general idea is not bad, I use it quite heavily.